# Finding all values of a set below the min() of a subset

Tags: sql, indexing, sql-server-2014

I'm using SQL Server 2014 and I have a table as the following

```
CREATE TABLE t_priority (
    Name     VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,
    Priority INT NOT NULL
);
```

I wish to find all records from this table where Priority is lower than the lowest priority associated with a name starting with 'foo'.

Here is currently my query

```
select t1.Name from t_priority t1 join 
(select min(Priority) as Priority, Name from t_priority where Name like 'foo%' ) t2 
on t1.Name != t2.Name 
and t1.Priority < t2.Priority;
```

One thing that bothers me is that I full scan twice the table (one for each leg of the join ? At least one physical read full scan and one logical full scan ?). I guess there should be a way to do it in one single scan.

Is it possible to achieve the same query result as the one above in one single scan ? I feel the ordering and fast access of an index would be usefull, so an index on Priority ? It would also be usefull for some other queries I got where I get all names where Priority equals a parametered value

A filtered index on Name seems usefull but the condition is too specific to create a permanent index and creating a short-lived one at runtime seems costly (filtered indexes are disk-based according to documentation)

Any other improvements of the above query are welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

You can express this as:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(case when name like 'foo%' then priority end) over () as min_foo_priority
      from t_priority t
     ) t
where priority < min_foo_priority;
```

Or:

```
select t.*
from t_priority t
where t.priority < (select min(tt.priority) from t_priority tt where tt.name like 'foo%');
```

For this version, you can create an index on `t_priority(name, priority)`, and the query may be able to make use of the index.

Your intuition that you can do this in one scan is off.  What would happen if the scan of the table is such that the very last row is the one with the minimum priority for "foo"?  You don't have enough information prior to that to accept or reject rows.

You could be efficient -- but through the use of an index.  The wildcarding on "foo" is problematic, but you can handle that with a persisted computed column.  So:

```
alter table t_priority add name3 as (left(name, 3)) persisted;

create index idx_priority_name3_priority on t_priority(name3, priority);
```

Then use `name3` in the query.  For instance:

```
select t.*
from t_priority t
where t.priority < (select min(tt.priority) from t_priority tt where tt.name3 = 'foo');
```